# PDF Reader for iOS

Tags: ios, pdf-reader

I had explored for a PDF Reader in iOS. I found out 2 useful libraries, Leaves PDF Reader and VFR - PDF Reader from Github. But  am having issues with these two libraries.

In the case of Leaves PDF Reader, I had integrated it with my application. If I did pinch zooming, the page will be zooming. But the texts in the pages will be blurred and could read it out.

In the case of PDF Reader from Github, it's a fully functional library. I like this reader most when compared to Leaves PDF Reader. But this library will render the PDF's perfectly if the PDF is taken from the bundle folder of the application. In my case, I wanted to integrate this with a newsstand application. So the downloading PDF's are stored in a cache library which is predefined for Newsstand application's library folder. If I gave this path as input to the PDF Reader library, the application got crashed. So I copied the PDF file from the newsstand library path to a NSDocument directory folder. Still the issue is same. This library render the PDF only if the PDF's are kept in the Bundle folder.

Can anybody help me in any of the above case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You can use the document viewer. This works fine for all type of files.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks Suresh, I hope this will help me. Do you know any other PDF Reader which is available from Github(VFR).

Comment: https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten

Comment: https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit